# JHipster - Unable to deploy to Heroku

Tags: heroku, jhipster

When I try to deploy to heroku using jhipster heroku command I get the below error.

```
SetupException: config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml does not exist
```

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to this. I am using the jhipster vue blueprint. In the Procfile there is a section that reads cp -R src/main/resources/config config.

This is the problem. The reason this fails is because that command copies the config directory inside of an existing config directory. So you end up with config/config instead of just config/.

So to fix this I modified the procfile to cp -R src/main/resources/config/* config